# What is the right way to handle NaN in Java?

Tags: java, double

For example, if you are computing the precision

```
p = correct / total
```

Would you make sure you don't divide by zero:

```
double p;
if (total == 0.0) {
  p = 0.0;
}
else {
  p == correct / total;
}
```

Or check if you get a NaN?

```
double p = correct / total;
if (Double.isNaN(p)) {
  p = 0.0;
}
```

Is there a benefit to an approach, or is it personal preference?

Comment: (I would consider the 2nd form because of cases like `NaN / x`, as per glowcoders reply to my comment)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the first approach, but instead of comparing to 0, I would compare the `Math.abs(total) < TOLERANCE` where TOLERANCE is some small value like 0.0001. This will prevent things very close to 0 from skewing results.

Comment: Can `some_double / very_close_to_but_not_zero` result in a NaN? I am unsure, but if not, it seems like a direct equals here (although questionable in the general case) is appropriate.

Comment: No, it won't result in a `NaN`. But it will result in an answer you may not want. Perhaps the `"very close but not zero"` was supposed to be zero, but due to floating point math ended up not zero. *Edit: if `some_double` is `NaN` yes it will, but I'm sure that's not what you were meaning. </edit>

Comment: Then that's another issue :) A +1 for you, but this is one case where, when I've done a vector library in the past, I've used `== 0` (it's a very precise requirement)